# Manual mock implementation of a nested React component with jest & enzyme

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing whether `OuterComponent` behaves correctly when its `InnerComponent` triggers some function calls. A simplified example:

```
// js/OuterComponent.js

onInput() {
  // Behaviour to test
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <InnerComponent onInput={() => this.onInput()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Because a pretty intricate chain of events has to happen for `InnerComponent` to finally call `this.props.onInput()`, I'd like to mock `InnerComponent` in my tests. I'm trying to do the following:

```
// tests/OuterComponent.test.js

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe("OuterComponent", () => {
  test("behaves correctly when receiving input", () => {
    jest.mock("../js/InnerComponent")
    const wrapper = shallow(<OuterComponent />);
    jest.runAllTimers();
    // expectations about OuterComponent after `onInput` has been called
  });
});
```

The mock:

```
// js/__mocks__/InnerComponent.js

export default class SVGSymbolDrawing extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.onInput();
    }, 100);
  }

  render() {
    return <div/>;
  }
}
```

My `expect`s are all failing, though. I can't see any console.logs from the InnerComponent mock, but I'm not sure how to test that it's actually using the mock rather than the real inner component.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking the whole InnerComponent you can call this function directly using `wrapper.instance()`, i.e. calling `wrapper.instance().onInput()`

Full example with passing test:

**OuterComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import InnerComponent from "./InnerComponent";

class OuterComponent extends Component {
  onClick() {
    this.setState({ clicked: true });
  }
  render() {
    return <InnerComponent onClick={() => this.onClick()} />;
  }
}
export default OuterComponent;
```

**InnerComponent.js**

```
const InnerComponent = ({onClick}) => <div onClick={onClick}>INNER</div>;
export default InnerComponent;
```

**OuterComponent.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Enzyme, { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import OuterComponent from "./OuterComponent.js";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("OuterComponent", () => {
  it("handles onClick", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<OuterComponent />);
    wrapper.instance().onClick();
    expect(wrapper.state('clicked')).toBe(true);
  });
});
```